# Cannot access to admin dashboard in Laravel on cloudways

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have deployed two Laravel projects (with Inertia.js and Jetstream Stack) to a Cloudways server with the same IP address. The first project was deployed under a subdomain, and the other one under a root domain. I can access the Laravel web via the subdomain but cannot access the admin dashboard via the root domain, nor can I log in to the website under a root domain. No errors were raised. I have been figuring it out for days, but to no avail. Have you had any experience before? What did I do wrong?